# Remove all instances of a character from string

Tags: c#, regex, string

I want to remove all instances of a character from a string except where that character is followed by any form or whitespace. I haven't written unit tests yet but it seems like the code below achieves what I want (possibly forgetting an edge case or two which is ok for now).  It feels pretty clunky though. Can anyone suggest an improvement?

```
public string Strip(string text, char c)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
    {
        bool characterIsInString = true;
        int currentIndex = 0;

        while (characterIsInString)
        {
            currentIndex = text.IndexOf(c, currentIndex + 1);

            if (currentIndex != -1)
            {
                var charAfter = text.Substring(currentIndex + 1, 1);

                if (charAfter != " ")
                {
                    text = text.Remove(currentIndex, 1);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                characterIsInString = false;
            }
        }
    }

    return text;
}
```

Comment: If your code works then there is no problem.  Try asking on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Regular Expression( here i have assumed that character is x):

```
string result = Regex.Replace( input , "x(?=\\S)" , "");
```

[Live Demo](https://regex101.com/r/KrYrEP/1). Please check that it uses very few steps finding it.

Comment: @maccettura nope, if you check steps, its a very simple pattern and is very fast acctually. I'm not a fan of regular expressions and try to avoid it as much as possible, but in such cases it does not seem reasonable to avoid regex and write lots of code.

Comment: @PoulBak your code removes all that followed by whitespace, OP wants to remove all except those followed by whitespace

Answer (score 1):

I suggest, you use the following code:

```
public string Strip(string text, char c)
{
    Regex regex = new Regex(c.ToString() + @"[^\s]");
    return regex.Replace(text, "");
}
```

This will remove the `char` in `text` if it's `not` followed by a White `Space`.

This is a very simple and fast regex.

Answer (score 0):

if you want replace character 
you can replace char with `Replace` method

Follow code:

```
Console.ReadLine().Replace("e","h");
```